# How to obtain the maximum/minimum value of a column and its corresponding index?

Tags: indexing, max, min, dolphindb

I have a table as follows (just to give an example):

```
date        ret1    ret2
2022.01.01  0.2844  0.9768
2022.01.02  0.1531  0.5791
2022.01.03  0.6683  0.418
2022.01.04  0.6441  0.8265
2022.01.05  0.3082  0.0918
2022.01.06  0.2197  0.5578
```

The first column is the date column and the rest of columns store the data of yield.

I want to obtain the maximum/minimum value of each column (exclude date column) and its corresponding date. For example, for column “ret1“, my expected result is 0.6683 (maximum)/2022.01.03 (date), and 0.1531 (minimum)/2022.01.02 (date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will create a table with random value that is similar to your given data in the question.

```
date=2022.01.01 + 0..31
ret1=rand(1.0,size(date))
ret2=rand(1.0,size(date))
tb=table(date,ret1,ret2)
```

…which looks like:

```
date        ret1    ret2
2022.01.01  0.1204  0.8332
2022.01.02  0.6071  0.0439
2022.01.03  0.8292  0.6409
2022.01.04  0.9989  0.0281
2022.01.05  0.779   0.4947
2022.01.06  0.8342  0.4477
2022.01.07  0.9014  0.0134
2022.01.08  0.5417  0.2441
2022.01.09  0.4288  0.0143
2022.01.10  0.4791  0.9859
2022.01.11  0.9654  0.2847
2022.01.12  0.4454  0.8206
2022.01.13  0.8525  0.8255
2022.01.14  0.0861  0.0172
2022.01.15  0.7788  0.2248
2022.01.16  0.2623  0.8577
2022.01.17  0.1601  0.9486
2022.01.18  0.1889  0.7622
2022.01.19  0.8978  0.1683
2022.01.20  0.1762  0.4089
2022.01.21  0.1804  0.8442
2022.01.22  0.4337  0.3034
2022.01.23  0.3838  0.6771
2022.01.24  0.778   0.2225
2022.01.25  0.0916  0.4198
2022.01.26  0.5623  0.2997
2022.01.27  0.8017  0.0754
2022.01.28  0.5301  0.1132
2022.01.29  0.8758  0.934
2022.01.30  0.1143  0.3779
2022.01.31  0.9446  0.5951
2022.02.01  0.1547  0.7291
```

And then define a function `f` using function `min`, `max`, `imin`, and `imax`:

```
def f(x,y,dates){
 return table(y as col,min(x) as min,max(x) as max,dates[imin(x)] as imin,dates[imax(x)] as imax)
}
unionAll(peach(f{,,tb.date},tb.values()[1:],colNames(tb)[1:]),0)
```

Run the script and you can get the results:

```
col     min     max     imin        imax
ret1    0.0861  0.9989  2022.01.14  2022.01.04
ret2    0.0134  0.9859  2022.01.07  2022.01.10
```